# PHP captcha wont show image

Tags: php, captcha

I made this code that is supposed to show me an image with text on it, but the image just wont appear. Any idea?

```
<?php

    header("Content-type: image/png"); 
    $md5 = md5(microtime() * mktime()); 

    $string = substr($md5,0,5);

    $captcha = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png'); 

    $black = imagecolorallocate($captcha, 0, 0, 0); 
    $line = imagecolorallocate($captcha,233,239,239); 

    imageline($captcha,0,0,39,29,$line); 
    imageline($captcha,40,0,64,29,$line);

    imagestring($captcha, 5, 20, 10, $string, $black); 

    $_SESSION['key'] = md5($string); 

    imagepng($captcha);
    imagedestroy($captcha);

?>
```

Comment: This code works for me. Try commenting out the header function and see if PHP displays any errors

Comment: You may as well look into your web server error log, to check for PHP errors (if `log_errors` is enabled in your php.ini).

Comment: Do you have the GD php extension installed? In Debian/Ubuntu: `apt-get install php5-gd`

Comment: thank you guys fixed it, he code had some problem with the mktime() function. Just used a different way to make a random number:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `mktime` that way you would get the following error `Strict standards: mktime() [function.mktime]` which would not make your Image display

Replace

```
$md5 = md5(microtime() * mktime());
```

With

```
$md5 = md5(microtime() * time());
```

Your Output

[image]

Comment: yap fixed it by the time, just had to remove the header to see the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP error log file, on my localhost I got several errors with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This script is working properly on my localhost.Please check `bg.png` exist in your folder or not. because if bg.png not found it generate error.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works also for me. 
You should check the path of your image

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$captcha = imagecreatefrompng(dirname(__FILE__) . '/bg.png');
```

Instead of:

```
$captcha = imagecreatefrompng('bg.png');
```